# SQL Server batch update, user-defined Table types

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-update

i need to batch updates on a table from a stored procedure that is has user defined table types. The updates are causing table locking and i would like to mitigate that.  I would like to batch them in updates of 1000.  The code would look as below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[updatestuff]
    @update1 AS udtupdate1 READONLY ,
    @update2 AS udtupdate2 READONLY ,
    @time DATETIME
AS 
    BEGIN       

    SET NOCOUNT ON        

-- uses udtupdate1      
        UPDATE  lms  
        SET     lms.col1 = lsp.col1 ,  
                lms.TimeStamp = @time 
        FROM    dbo.tlivetable1 lms  
                INNER JOIN @update1 lsp ON lms.livetable1Id = lsp.colId    


        UPDATE  ms
        SET     ms.col1 = lsp.col1 ,
                ms.TimeStamp = @time
        FROM    dbo.tmrks ms
                INNER JOIN @update1  lsp ON ms.mrksId = lsp.Colid    

-- uses udtupdate2

        UPDATE  mms
        SET     mms.col2 = msp.col2 ,
                mms.Date = @time
        FROM    dbo.tMMSel mms
                INNER JOIN @update2 msp ON msp.col1Id = mms.MMId
                AND msp.col2Id = mms.MMSId

END
```

Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this as I don't have any sample data but this should do it.:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[updatestuff]
    @update1 AS udtupdate1 READONLY ,
    @update2 AS udtupdate2 READONLY ,
    @time DATETIME
AS 
    BEGIN       

    SET NOCOUNT ON        

    WHILE (1 = 1)
    BEGIN
       BEGIN TRANSACTION

       UPDATE top (1000)  lms  
          SET     lms.col1 = lsp.col1 ,  
                lms.TimeStamp = @time 
          FROM    dbo.tlivetable1 lms  
                INNER JOIN @update1 lsp ON lms.livetable1Id = lsp.colId   

       IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 -- terminating condition;
        BEGIN
          COMMIT TRANSACTION
          BREAK
        END

       COMMIT TRANSACTION
    --WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'; --<-- you can uncomment wait for delay to increase the delay between batches
    END

    WHILE (1 = 1)
    BEGIN
       BEGIN TRANSACTION

          UPDATE top (1000)  ms
          SET     ms.col1 = lsp.col1 ,
                ms.TimeStamp = @time
          FROM    dbo.tmrks ms
                INNER JOIN @update1  lsp ON ms.mrksId = lsp.Colid     

       IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 -- terminating condition;
        BEGIN
          COMMIT TRANSACTION
          BREAK
        END

       COMMIT TRANSACTION
    --WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'; --<-- you can uncomment wait for delay to increase the delay between batches
    END

    WHILE (1 = 1)
    BEGIN
       BEGIN TRANSACTION

          UPDATE top (1000)  mms
          SET     mms.col2 = msp.col2 ,
                mms.Date = @time
          FROM    dbo.tMMSel mms
                INNER JOIN @update2 msp ON msp.col1Id = mms.MMId
                AND msp.col2Id = mms.MMSId  

       IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 -- terminating condition;
        BEGIN
          COMMIT TRANSACTION
          BREAK
        END

       COMMIT TRANSACTION
    --WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'; --<-- you can uncomment wait for delay to increase the delay between batches
    END

END
```

Comment: Thankyou for this, i will be testing and keep you posted